# Rewrite Rules problem when rule includes homepage slug

Tags: rewrite-rules, homepage, variables, home-url

I have page Example (ID=443, slug=example) that is configured, through `Dashboard->Settings->Reading`, as the home page of my WP site. I also have the following rewrite rule configured:

```
[(example)/(view-section)] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&foo=1&bar=2
```

I have a shortcode in the Example page that should generate content based on presence and value of `foo`and `bar`query vars. The problem is the query vars are not properly set when I visit the URL `/example/view-section` (and others related, see below).

I'm using a test plugin to debug this issue only. The complete code is below:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
<?php

function test_shortcode() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    echo '<pre>' . 'foo: ' . get_query_var('foo') . '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>' . 'bar: ' . get_query_var('bar') . '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($wp_rewrite->rules, true) . '</pre>';
}
add_shortcode('foobar', 'test_shortcode');

function test_rules() {
    $rules = get_option('rewrite_rules');
    if (!isset($rules['(example)/(view-section)'])) {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    }
}
add_action('wp_loaded', 'test_rules');


function test_rewrite_rules($wprules) {
    $rules = array('(example)/(view-section)' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&foo=1&bar=2');
    return $rules + $wprules;
}
add_action('rewrite_rules_array', 'test_rewrite_rules');


function test_query_vars($query_vars) {
    array_push($query_vars, 'foo');
    array_push($query_vars, 'bar');
    return $query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'test_query_vars');
```

There are three scenarios that gave me different results:

1. Going to /example/view-section redirects to / and the query vars values are empty.
2. Going to /index.php?pagename=example&foo=1&bar=2 works the way I needed. Showing the content generated by the shortcode and the value of the two query vars passed in the URL.
3. If I use `page_id` instead of `pagename` or `page`: /index.php?page_id=443&foo=1&bar=2, the `page_id` query var is removed and the default homepage is shown again.

I would like to know why is WP behaving as described above and, if possible, how to make the first case, at least, work like the second one.

Please note that if the Example page is not configured as the homepage, cases 1 and 3 work as the case 2.

I appreciate your help and will be happy to provide more details if necessary.

**EDIT**

The question originally included links to a running WP instance with an example of the problem. However, I can't keep that instance running forever, so I removed the links and tried to explain the situation with words only.

Comment: What happens if you save your permalink settings again, and then try?

Comment: @Stephen Harris, I get same results. I think saving permalinks again has the same effect that calling `flush_rewrite_rules` or `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules`, does it?. Also you can see in the results page that the rule is being properly added to `$wp_rewrite->rules` array. Thks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the rewrite rules (though I would suggest using [`add_rewrite_rule()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) rather than the more low level approach of altering the rewrite array directly. The same for [`flush_rewrite_rules()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules). Also, although as you have it the rules are only flushed once - it would be better to do it on the activation of the plug-in, rather than inside a conditional which is checked on every page load.

... so the 'problem' is actually [canonicalisation](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139066).  Basically various urls can point to the same content (including urls with just additional forward-slashes). The idea is that

1. This is not good for a seo perspective - if search engines don't realise that all these url represent the same resource, they may end up competing with each other
2. Not good from a user perspective. If they go to *www.example.com?year=2012* it would be to redirect them to *www.example.com/2012* - prettier and easier to remember.

So, when WordPress receives a 'broken' or 'duplicate' url such *www.example.com?year=2012* it redirects it to the correct (or 'canonical') url. (*www.example.com/2012*) in this case.

One of the checks it performs is whether we are on the 'home page', and if we are - it checks that we are using the canonical url for our home page: http://108.166.64.229/ in your case. If not, you are redirected here. You'll notice that  http://108.166.64.229/example redirects to there to.

You *can* turn this off. Canonicalisation is run on the `template_redirect` hook. So you can simply remove it:

```
remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical');
```

Or you can 'undo' it (in the specific instance of your front say), by using a hook that is used inside the `redirect_canonical` callback

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical', 'wpse51530_redirect_canonical', 10, 2);

function wpse51530_redirect_canonical($redirect_url, $requested_url){
    if( is_front_page() )
        return $requested_url;
    else
        return $redirect_url;
}
```

You can see how WordPress does canonicalisation [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.3.2/wp-includes/canonical.php).

Comment: Thank you @StephenHarris, that's a great explanation for the the problem I have and your suggestions pointed me right to the solution.